# Angular | Update input with pipe strategy

Tags: angular, input, pipe

I had this task about number input and decimal pipe in Angular. I wondered if there is a pros and cons of using **decimalPipe.transform** function when **ngModelChange** happens vs when **blur** happens? I want to hear your thoughts about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I fully understand your question but here are few thoughts on the pipe. You can configure the pipe to be pure or not. Pure = false, means it will run once per change detection cycle in the template, or pure = true means it will run whenever the reference to the object in the pipe changes. So its more efficient.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'flyingHeroesImpure',
  pure: false
})
```

the on blur event handler, will be triggered only when the blur event happens. Depends on what you need.

Comment: I think it's depends on the business logic and user experience. but I think in many business logic the transformation needs call when ever value change.

Comment: Pure and impure feature affects the template but not when we use it in ts file. I was asking about input AND blur/ngModelChange. ngModelChange is triggered immediately when change happens, but blur when you step out of the input. So the pipe transformation on the functions can be essential during those events.

Comment: If you use ngModelChange and transform input value with decimalPipe and digitInfo:1.2-2 then if you delete the second decimal it will immediately place 0 instead of deleting the character. If there is 2.15 and you press delete on 5 it will automatically set to 2.10 because of the rule of digitInfo. But if you do the same function on blur it wont trigger the function and after deleting '5' you will get 2.1